# Authenticate Azure AD User Using Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

First of all let me explain the scenario.

Dev Technology

- Blazor ( Any SPA)
- .Net Core API

1. I have Azure B2C tenant. My application authentication and authorization is configured using Azure B2C.
2. Now there is some busines related requirement in which external azure active directory user needs to add Azure B2C and at the same time it will get authenticate using external Azure AD.

Is this valid scenario and is this possible ?

### Update

Let me give some more insight and example.

1. I have b2c tenant name mytenantpoc.
2. I am working in pocorganization and they have Azure AD tenant and my user is there with like user1@pocorganization.com. This is work account.
3. Now If I invite this user1@pocorganization.com to B2C tenant then it will land as a external active directory user and if I assign some role then it is also possible that user manage Azure B2C tenant.

Now I am working on one Blazor application and it required some authentication. So I have registered application B2C.

Problem: If I now try to login with user1@pocoranization.com then it is not working.

What is working : If I create new user in B2C then it is working.

What I am looking for: I want to use Azure AD user in B2C and their authentication will perform.

Comment: this scenario is possible where you can register user and then authenticate using the same, i  have already written some console application long time back where adding the user in azure ad dynamically, have a look hope this will help https://github.com/rahulshukla422/azure-ad-register-user

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invite a user to B2C, they become an admin. user **NOT** a local user.

In this scenario, you need to use federation i.e add the azure AD instance as an [external provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider).

Comment: They do not automatically become "admin"...unless you add to one of the built-in Admin role. When using federation as well, when the federated user is accessing the B2C first time, the user flow must be of the kind "sign up and sign in", otherwise it fails with error `AADB2C99002: User does not exist.`

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to invite this account to your AAD B2C. Inviting an account only does what you stated, for the purpose of managing admin tasks in the Azure Portal for your B2C tenant.

You need to add Azure AD as a federated identity provider to your B2C user flow. That will allow users to login from other AAD’s.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

If you want to restrict logins to specific accounts from another AAD, then you want to apply some sort of RBAC solution or attribute based RBAC.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/relying-party-rbac

Answer (score 0):

I think you can invite external AD users as guest on tour tenant and then permit login to local accounts on your B2C

Update
To permits local accounts you have to change the user flow (or custom policy if your are using that)

Comment: Updated my question. I have performed this activity but I am able to login with this user. I have to create new B2C user and then seems to be a problem.

Comment: Does your user flow (or custom policy) permits sign in to local accounts?

Comment: Yes. So If I create local account into B2C it works fine but the invited user authentication is not get success. This is same problem that mention in this question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/255659/how-can-i-invite-guest-users-to-azure-b2c-platform.html.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You cannot allow invited accounts to authenticate to B2C user flow or custom policy.