# Azure B2C Signup For External Provider and Sign In for Local Provider

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

This is extension to this question that I have already asked.
[Authenticate Azure AD User Using Azure B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316971/authenticate-azure-ad-user-using-azure-b2c)

Now with suggested solution over there, I can add Azure Ad as an OpenId provider.

Only problem is that, I have to sign in / sign up flow for this. I only want to use Sign In flow as requirement is that user will preconfigured into Azure B2C and only those user allow to access application so sign up needs to disable. This work for local account but external AD if user is not created in B2C as part of Sign up process then it will not work.

Is there any specific way that Sign up only for external AD.

Comment: Sample here https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/link-local-account-with-federated-account

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Thanks for this. I will try this out. For userflow it is easy to configure. Like for future point of view is that possible to configure multiple Azure AD.